# Calculate opening balance

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need some help on calculating a Running Balance. Below is output of table `D009040`.

```
LBrCode MainAcctId  EntryDate   SetNo   DrCr    FcyTrnAmt
15  20060000000000030000000100000000    4/27/2015   11332   C   200
15  20060000000000030000000100000000    5/7/2015    8050    D   500
15  20060000000000030000000100000000    5/18/2015   11270   D   500
15  20060000000000030000000100000000    6/1/2015    13009   C   500
15  20060000000000030000000100000000    6/28/2015   81916   C   22.17
15  20060000000000030000000100000000    7/20/2015   11196   C   500
15  20060000000000030000000100000000    4/20/2015   11127   C   1000
15  20060000000000030000000100000000    4/28/2015   88017   C   6.37
15  20060000000000030000000100000000    5/11/2015   11176   D   500
15  20060000000000030000000100000000    5/25/2015   11201   D   300
15  20060000000000030000000100000000    6/15/2015   11075   C   500
15  20060000000000030000000100000000    7/6/2015    11069   C   500
15  20060000000000030000000100000000    7/28/2015   97098   C   32.43
15  20060000000000030000000100000000    4/16/2015   1019    C   3000
15  20060000000000030000000100000000    4/27/2015   11333   D   200
15  20060000000000030000000100000000    5/11/2015   11175   C   500
15  20060000000000030000000100000000    5/25/2015   11200   C   500
15  20060000000000030000000100000000    6/8/2015    10700   C   500
15  20060000000000030000000100000000    6/29/2015   11464   C   500
15  20060000000000030000000100000000    7/27/2015   10701   C   500
15  20060000000000030000000100000000    4/20/2015   11128   D   1000
15  20060000000000030000000100000000    5/7/2015    8049    C   500
15  20060000000000030000000100000000    5/18/2015   11269   C   500
15  20060000000000030000000100000000    5/28/2015   82065   C   14.86
15  20060000000000030000000100000000    6/22/2015   11101   C   500
15  20060000000000030000000100000000    7/13/2015   11401   C   500
```

I want to calculate Debit and Credit entries, and get the running balance for each date. I'm using below query.

```
SELECT CM.LBrCode, CM.MainAcctId, CM.EntryDate,
       sum(CASE WHEN CM.DrCr='C' THEN CM.FcyTrnAmt
                WHEN CM.DrCr='D' THEN CM.FcyTrnAmt * -1 END)
           OVER (PARTITION BY CM.MainAcctId ORDER BY CM.SetNo) As Amount, 
       sum(CASE WHEN CM.DrCr='C' THEN CM.FcyTrnAmt
                WHEN CM.DrCr='D' THEN CM.FcyTrnAmt * -1 END)
           OVER (PARTITION BY CM.MainAcctId ORDER BY CM.SetNo) As Amount
FROM D009040 CM
```

It calculates the running balance, but if there are two transactions on same day it calculates and shows two balances. My requirement is if there are two transactions for same day, then do debit or credit and show the single latest balance for the date.

Any idea on how I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

Probably something like this:

```
; WITH Base AS
(
    SELECT MIN(CM.LBrCode) LBrCode,
           CM.MainAcctId,
           CM.EntryDate,
           MIN(CM.SetNo) SetNo,
           SUM(CASE
             WHEN CM.DrCr = 'C' THEN CM.FcyTrnAmt
             WHEN CM.DrCr = 'D' THEN CM.FcyTrnAmt * -1
           END) FcyTrnAmt
    FROM   #D009040 CM
    GROUP BY CM.MainAcctId, CM.EntryDate
)

SELECT B.LBrCode,
       B.MainAcctId,
       B.EntryDate,
       B.FcyTrnAmt,
       SUM(B.FcyTrnAmt) OVER (PARTITION BY B.MainAcctId ORDER BY B.SetNo) Balance
       FROM Base B
```

I first calculate the total movements for the day in `Base`, then I do the running total in the second `SELECT`. Note that I don't like very much the fact that the first `SELECT` is grouped by `EntryDate` (so giving the "day" of the operation the most importance), while the second `SELECT` is `ORDER BY` `SetNo`, this because the first operation can/will make some `SetNo` "disappear" (the `MIN(CM.SetNo)`)